# jquery animate happens instantly (using angular)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation

I'm trying to move a div (itemEl) by animating its css attributes using jQuery.animate. I have the code working in a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/29GCU1D2eFebEpFFf96Q?p=preview), but when trying to port it to my project, the animation broke. That is to say, the div is actually moved to the correct position, but this happens instantly, instead of over time. This is an excerpt from my directive's controller:

```
// draw item in fixed position
itemEl.css({
    position        :'absolute',
    top             : itemElPos.top,           
    left            : itemElPos.left,                
    width           : itemElDim.width,
    height          : itemElDim.height,
});



// move item to overlap mainItem
var animationPointer = itemEl.animate({
        position  : 'absolute',
        top     : mainItemElPos.top,                
        left    : mainItemElPos.left,               
        width   : mainItemElDim.width,
        height  : mainItemElDim.height,
    },
    1000,
    function(mainItem, itemEl){return function(){

       // process after animation

    };}(mainItem, itemEl)
);
```

Does anyone know where I should look to fix this issue? Maybe there's a compatibility issue between jquery animate & angular's ngAnimate? Or some deprecated method or some global setting... I have no clue :p

---------------------------- SOLVED:

There turned out to be a compatibility issue between jQuery.animate() and datejs. Datejs for some reason overwrites Date.now, causing a Date object to be returned instead of an integer. Modifying datejs's source solved my problems!

Comment: Can you post a plunkr of the code that isn't working?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's part of a larger project that I'm working on. The excerpt I posted comes from a method in the controller of a custom directive I'm using. It's called through an ng-click inside the template. From debugging I can see that the code does execute, I get no errors or warnings and the div actually moves. It moves instantly though, as if the delay time were set to 0, instead of 1000ms.

Comment: As the problem is caused by something outside of the question it will be difficult for anyone to help. Best advice I can give is to take a copy of your project and delete as much as possible until this small bit starts working...then maybe you can post whatever code was in the tipping point.